# How to prevent mxGraph GraphEditor automatically applying blue colouring to loaded diagrams

Tags: mxgraph

I've got a customised instance of GraphEditor in a view in an ASP.NET MVC app and I've got it set to use a database for diagram persistence. When opening, I've programmed it to create a new model to initialise the graph using the model data stored in the database. This works, except that vertexes and edges that were black and white when saved become blue when loaded. I'm guessing there's some default mxGraph style variable that's responsible for this, but I'm not sure. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, in case it's useful to anyone else, I actually found the solution. The default colours are defined in mxClient as hexadecimals and can be replaced with whatever you want to use.

Comment: i need help for mxgraph dm me your mail